# yii2, процесс создания модуля

Tags: yii2, composer, packagist

Есть несколько вопросов по процессу разработки модуля для yii2

У меня есть стандартное `yii2-app-basic` приложение. Я разрабатываю свой модуль и тестирую его в этом приложении. Сам модуль лежит в папке `modules/gallery`. Например, в файле `modules/gallery/Module.php` используется такое пространство имен - `namespace app\modules\gallery;`

теперь я хочу создать отдельный репозиторий конкретно для своего модуля, а также потом разместить его `packagist` (чтоб с `composer` можно устанавливать). в связи с этим возникает несколько проблем

1) получается, мне нужно везде в папке моего модуля неймспейсы вида `namespace app\modules\gallery;` поменять на другие (ну например `user/gallery`). Если делать это прямо внутри папки `modules/gallery`, то перестанет работать мой тестовый `basic` сайт. если выносить модуль в отдельную папку, создавать репозиторий там и там же переименовывать, то как вести дальнейшую разработку модуля? в той папке я уже не смогу протестить модуль с помощью своего `basic` приложения...можете описать, как это делаете вы? как разрабатываете, тестируете модуль, в какие папки его помещаете, какие неймспейсы прописываете, как потом заливаете на `github`...

2) предположим, я разместил модуль на `packagist` и могу устанавливать его с помощью composer в папку vendor. а если я хочу внести большие изменения в этот модуль? получается, я не могу работать в папке `vendor`, т.к. `composer` все перезапишет. в таком случае мне все делать вручную, без помощи композера копипастить папки и т.д.? как это делаете вы?

Comment: Отвечу по второму вопросу: чтобы composer не перезаписал ваши правки, вам требуется наследоваться от класса и уже в основном коде проекта перегружать требуемые методы, либо расширять функциональность.

Answer (score 3):

Можете смело менять namespace внутри своего модуля. Все что нужно для того чтобы он заработал в вашем приложении -- это указать в конфиге приложения корректный [alias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html):

```
$config = [
    ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@user/gallery' => '@app/modules/gallery',
    ]
    ...
]
```

Эта опция даёт автолоадеру Yii2 инструкцию искать файлы, которые в соответствии с [`PSR-4`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) должны быть в папке `/user/gallery`, в папке `@app/modules/gallery`.

При установке через composer (обычно в папку `@app/vendor`) этого делать не придётся, т.к. composer использует собственный автолоадер.

Само собой, все директивы `namespace` внутри вашего модуля должны следовать стандарту [`PSR-4`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), т.е. в папке `@app/modules/gallery/path/to/folder` должен быть `namespace user\gallery\path\to\folder` и т.д.